# Existe-t-il une traduction de « framework » ?

Tags: traduction, informatique, demande-de-mot

Tout est dit dans le titre.

Il est (de plus en plus) courant de parler dans l'informatique de *framework*. [Les traductions que propose WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/framework) n'incluent aucune proposition pour l'informatique :

> - (Construction) charpente, structure
> - cadre, système

Dans les faits, je ne crois jamais avoir entendu de mot français dans le contexte informatique pour *framework*. Ce contexte est bien évidemment favorable aux anglicismes mais je serais heureux de trouver une tournure française élégante.

[Wikipédia propose « structure logicielle »](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framework) mais cela ne me semble pas éclairer l'interlocuteur sur ce que cachent ces termes. « Kit de développement » ou « boîte à outils logiciels » me paraîtraient déjà plus adaptés, sans toutefois représenter une fois de plus ce qu'est exactement le framework.

Concrètement (et en résumant), un framework informatique est généralement un ensemble d'outils permettant de faciliter la pose des fondations d'une application logicielle. Il se distingue des bibliothèques<sup>1</sup> par son caractère générique là où les premières sont souvent très spécialisées, ainsi que par l'introduction de recommandations ou lignes de conduites (une des traductions littérales de *framework* étant « cadre de travail »). L'utilisation d'un framework doit permettre de mettre rapidement en place un squelette du logiciel à écrire.

Cela fait beaucoup de notions à résumer en quelques mots, mais peut-être quelqu'un a-t-il une meilleure proposition que ce qui se trouve actuellement.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Très bon exemple des anglicismes courants en informatique, on parle souvent de *librairies* par homophonie avec le terme utilisé en anglais : *library*. Un anglicisme francisé par une erreur courante, donc.</sub>